# Python Big Query Error : google.api_core.exceptions.BadRequest: 400 Cannot set destination table in jobs with DML statements

Tags: python, google-bigquery

I am working on Python code to execute BigQuery sql Deletion command  statement using bigquery.Client.query. I am getting Cannot set destination table in jobs with DML statements exception.
Beforehand I can use Selection statments perfectly fine but errors out when it comes to deletion

Below is the Python code I am using

```
from google.cloud import bigquery

# TODO(developer): Construct a BigQuery client object.
client = bigquery.Client()

# TODO(developer): Set table_id to the ID of the destination table.
table_id = "ny.test.blue_test"

job_config = bigquery.QueryJobConfig(destination=table_id)
job_config.write_disposition = 'WRITE_APPEND'

sql = """
    Delete 
    FROM 
    `ny.test.blue` 
    WHERE name = 'Beat';
"""

# Start the query, passing in the extra configuration.
query_job = client.query(sql, job_config=job_config)  # Make an API request.
query_job.result()  # Wait for the job to complete.

print("Query results loaded to the table {}".format(table_id))
```

Any Ideas on how to bypass this error?

Answer (score 0):

As you are using DML to delete data in a specific table, you are not storing data in another table (destination table).

Destination table is [optional](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/Job#JobConfigurationQuery.FIELDS.destination_table) as well is write_disposition.

you only need to run the DML query.

As the error says:
"Cannot set destination table in jobs with DML statements"

Comment: Well that what I am attempting to do in this case delete from one table, append the ouput(results of deletion) to anothet table(destination table). If I am understanding correctly just running the dml query by itself should work?

Comment: Destination table is to save the query result in a table. In the case of a DML statement you are not creating a result, you are just deleting rows. So first you run the query and save the result in the destination table and then you run the DML statement.